# Add strings and tags at the beginning and end of each line

Tags: regex, linux, string, text-processing, cat

I have recently started using Ubuntu and catching up on lots of stuff - can somebody please assist a little bit.

I have a file (pictures.txt) with 300 lines like this:

```
Kitchen 
Cookie 
Soup 
Garden 
Flower 
Make-up
```

I would like to add a tag, prepend a string and add ending tags to each line in the file (i.e. for every entry in the pictures.txt file), so I get something like this:

```
<m>
<img id="1"> Kitchen <img> 
</m>
<m>
<img id="2"> Cookie <img> 
</m>
<m>
<img id="3"> Soup <img> 
</m>
<m>
<img id="4"> Garden <img> 
</m>
<m>
<img id="5"> Flower <img>  
</m>
<m>
<img id="6"> Make-up <img> 
</m>
```

I tried "cat -n pictures.txt" so far, but I see no option to add additional strings or tags (besides rising numbers) at the beginning or end of each line.

I hope this question is not too stupid.

Thanks all,
Monique

Comment: The question isn't _stupid_ but doesn't demonstrate _any effort_ on your part to solve the problem.

Comment: I would probably write a simple c code for completing this task. Whenever you get a '\n' character you could add your desired text. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it with GNU sed:

```
cat -n pictures.txt | sed 's: *\([0-9]*\)\t\(.*\):<m>\n<img id="\1"> \2 </img>\n</m>:'
```

Output:

```
<m>
<img id="1"> Kitchen  </img>
</m>
<m>
<img id="2"> Cookie  </img>
</m>
<m>
<img id="3"> Soup  </img>
</m>
<m>
<img id="4"> Garden  </img>
</m>
<m>
<img id="5"> Flower  </img>
</m>
<m>
<img id="6"> Make-up </img>
</m>
```